# How to fix int to float for function tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, error-handling

So i am trying to create a function that checks if a user inputs a str content it will print out an error message saying `print("You can only use a number ranging from 1 - 4, setting minimum_offer to 1.")`

but when I run my code it says this as the error code:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:/Python Code stuff I did/print.py", line 218, in <lambda>
    button = Button(root,text="Change Config", width=20, height=3, bg="#0f0f0f",fg="#ffffff", command=lambda:[do_it(), do_it1(), do_it2(), do_it3(),do_the_it(),do_the_it1()])
  File "d:/Python Code stuff I did/print.py", line 42, in do_it
    userInput = number.get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 537, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "wa"
```

This is my code that gives the error:

```
number_1 = StringVar()
def do_the_it():
    userinput4 = number_1.get()
    try:
        int(userinput4)
        updater.read('settings.ini')
        updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_offer'].value = number_1.get()
        updater.update_file()
    except Exception as error:
        print("You can only use a number ranging from 1 - 4, setting minimum_offer to 1.")
        updater.read('settings.ini')
        updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_offer'].value = 1
        updater.update_file()

    updater.read('settings.ini')
    updater['Trading Settings']['maximum_offer'].value = number_2.get()
    updater.update_file()
    a = updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_offer'].value
    if int(number_1.get()) > 4:
        print("Number can only exceed to 4")
        updater.read('settings.ini')
        updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_offer'].value = 1
        updater.update_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

For error handling, you would have to check whether the transformation to `int` is actually possible. You could use a try-block.

```
accept = True
try:
    tmp = int(number_1.get())
except:
    accept = False
```

Then you can only execute the second part (the if-block) if accept is true:

```
if accept:
    if int(number_1.get()) > 4:
        ### Rest of your code
else:
    print("Enter a number you joker")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `number_1.get()` inside the `try` block:

```
def do_the_it():
    try:
        val = int(number_1.get())
        if not 1 <= val <= 4:
            raise ValueError
    except (ValueError, TclError):
        print('You can only use a number ranging from 1 - 4, setting minimum_offer to 1.')
        val = 1
    
    updater.read('settings.ini')
    updater['Trading Settings']['minimum_offer'].value = val
    updater.update_file()
```